# Merge two obervables but to not trigger the second one until the first one completes

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two modal dialogs, selection and confirmation. Here is the working code:

```
this.newClientId.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
    response => this.confirmDialogService.ask('DSf').pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
        answer => answer ? this.createOrder(response) : this.goBack.next()
    )
);
```

Selection dialog puts the value into the newClientId and after that the confirmation dialog is triggered and when user confirms creation then the new order is created.

Is this possible to make without nesting?

All suggestions I have found here trigger the confirmation dialog before the newClientID is set.

Comment: Why you don't do it in same dialog?

Comment: without nesting, i dont think so. But you should use switchMap or something

Comment: @DmitriyKavraiskyi Target clientele needs more hand-holding then an average user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MERGING INNER AND OUTER OBSERVABLE VALUES:**

For merging the inner and outer observable values, you can use the `switchMap` rxjs operator.

```js
this.newClientId
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap(
      clientId => this.confirmDialogService.ask('DSf'),
      (clientId, answer) => [clientId, answer]
    )
  )
  .subscribe(([clientId, answer]) => {
    console.log(`Received client id is: ${clientId} and confirmation from user is: ${answer}`);
    // Perform your logic now
  });
```

There are multiple overrided versions for the `switchMap` operator and I have shown the one with **selector function** (have a close look at the second argument of the operator). Generally if selector function is ommited, only the value of the inner observable is returned. You can use the selector function to customize your output to include the values of both outer and inner observables by combining them into an array as shown in the example above.

Check out the [demo rxjs app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-trde4y) I have created for your usecase in stackblitz.

For more information on switchMap and selector functions in switchMap, refer this [article](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-switchmap-operator/). I highly recommend to go through this article if this is the first time you are using the `switchMap` operator.

**ALTERNATIVE METHOD:**

From your code snippet, I understand that you are only interested in the first value of the observable. In that case instead of merging observables, you can use Promises and ES6 `async-await` syntax to come up with an elegant and easy solution.

With Promises and async-await, you can change your code snippet as below:

```js
async getResult() {
  let clientId = await this.newClientId.toPromise();
  let answer = await this.confirmDialogService.ask('DSf'),toPromise();
  // perform your logic
}
```

In the above code snippet, `confirmDialogService.ask()` method will not be called until `newClientId` returns a result. So async calls happens synchronously now and only after the 2 async calls are finished (in the order specified), it will execute rest of the code in the method.

**EDIT :** Updated the answer to solve the problem using rxjs operator.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I am aware that my snippet can be solved in different ways but I am interested in a proper RxJS solution for learning purposes.

Comment: @darko99 Updated my answer by including a solution using rxjs operators.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done with the `switchMap` operator to switch to a new observable once one emits.

Try:

```
this.newClientId.pipe(
 take(1),
 switchMap(response => {
   return [of(response), this.confirmDialogService.ask('DSf')];
 }
 take(1),
).subscribe(([response, answer])=> answer ? this.createOrder(response) : this.goBack.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple way to combine two Observables into with the rx.zip operator to avoid nested subscriptions

```js
const client$ : Observable<object> = this.newClientId.pipe(take(1))
const dialog$ : Observable<object> = this.confirmDialogService.ask('DSf').pipe(take(1)) //  Why take(1) ? 

zip(client$, dialog$).subscribe( ([response, answer])) => {
  answer ? this.createOrder(response) : this.goBack.next();
}
```

And could you elaborate, why you use "pipe(take(1))" in both cases? Maybe this would change my answer.

Is clientId a Observable or a BehaviourSubject ?

Comment: `pipe(take(1))` is for completion purpose since both streams need to emit only once. Both are Subject - newClientId emits number and dialog emits boolean after user selection. It is not flattening that puzzles me but fine grain control of executing order of subscriptions. Your proposed solution doesn't work in this UI context because confirmation dialog is displayed before newClientId is emitted instead of after.

Comment: did you try? 
this should not matter since zip only applies if there ist one value in both subjects. 
Since dialog emits just only one value by design. the take(1) is not needed.

Comment: I did try. Didn't work as I need it because dialog is displayed before newCliendIt is emitted

Comment: Ah ok, so your dialog needs the client data ? 

Could you elaborate how your dialog recieves the client date, and how do you emit a client value ?